# How to listen to auth state changed in aws cognito?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using aws cognito for authentication solution in my react app. I am instead of using the components provided by aws react package, I am using apis in the aws javascript library. I want to listen to the auth state changed.

After googling and going over aws docs I still can't find any such method.

How can I listen to changes in the auth state?

Comment: Are you using [amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js)?

Comment: @JamesSouth I am using amplify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplify provides a utility object called Hub that can listen to auth state changes.

See sample documentation here: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/auth-events/q/platform/js

The way I use it is by setting it up in a custom hook that gets injected into the app.tsx file.

Comment: Thanks, I spend a huge amount of time and ended up with polling. I will use hub now